# Return first Number of each row?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have this text and I want to replace each line with the first number that occurs in the line.

E.g.:

```
Affiliate,"0,00Â â‚¬","1,13","0,00Â â‚¬","0,00Â â‚¬","0,00Â %"
Bing - brand,"45,11Â â‚¬","0,31","145,98Â â‚¬","0,00Â â‚¬","0,00Â %"
Bing - nonbrand,"39,90Â â‚¬","0,00","0,00Â â‚¬","0,00Â â‚¬","0,00Â %"
```

Would become:

```
0,00
45,11
39,90
```

Can you help me on that?

My so far regex is:

```
(.*),"(.*),"(.*),"(.*),"(.*),"(.*)
```

with output $2

But that looks terrible and also doesn't give me the wanted result.

Comment: Which tool/editor/lib do you use? Do you have `grep ` ?

Comment: i use notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^\D*(\d+(?:,\d+)?).*$
Replace: $1
```

Here is an explanation of the regex pattern:

- `^` from the start of the line
- `\D*` consume zero or more non digit characters
- `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` match and capture in `$1` the first digit, with optional decimal
- `.*` consume the rest of the line
- `$` end of the line

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ISANjF/1).

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex::

```
^.*?"(\d+\,\d+).*
$1
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `.*?` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the least amount possible)) |
| `"` | " |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\,` | , |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: Thank you Gilles =) ! 

As I can only mark one Answer as right, I will go for Tims one.

But thanks a lot=)

Comment: This gives `Affiliate,"0,00` for the first line. Wrong usage of `\K`.

Comment: I remove \K, not needed